# OpenCV bitwise_and produces original image and not masked image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, scatter-plot, bitwise-and

I am trying to group scatter points which are of same color using hsv values, I am able to create a mask (as seen below) but when I try to do a bitwise_and operation on the original image(og_image) and the mask, the result is always the original image and not the masked image. Am I doing something wrong over here? Any help would be appreciated. thanks in advance!

Original Image -

[image: Orignal_image]

mask(for indianred color) -

[image: mask]

output -

[image: output]

here is the code -

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import copy

def extract_colors(image):
    # Convert the image to HSV color space.
    hsv_image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    ## some processing
    return hsv_image, #colors


def remove_black_white(img):
    # some processing to detect pixels with same r,g,b values
    colors = set() # a set of colors with same r,g,b values
    for color in colors:
        img[np.all(img==color, axis=-1)] = (0,0,0)
    return img

if __name__ == "__main__":
    image = cv2.imread("875.png")
    og_image = copy.deepcopy(image)
    black_img = remove_black_white(image)
    hsvImage, colors = extract_colors(black_img)
    result = copy.deepcopy(og_image)
    lower = np.array([min_h, min_s, min_v], dtype=np.uint8)
    upper = np.array([max_h, max_s, max_v], dtype=np.uint8)
    mask = cv2.inRange(hsvImage, lower, upper)
    res = cv2.bitwise_and(og_image, og_image, mask)
    cv2.imshow('mask_'+k, mask)
    cv2.imshow('masked_image_'+k, res)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Kindly help!

Comment: "I understand the code is too long, but many functions are of no relevance to the question (as far as I can tell)." Then why are they there? If the question is whether you are applying `bitwise_and` properly, surely all that is necessary is the original image, the mask image, and the few lines of code to demonstrate the result of `bitwise_and`. And there is no call to `bitwise_and` in your code.

Comment: My bad, sorry for the confusion, I have edited the code and removed unnecessary clutter.

Comment: Please post original images, not screen captures, so that your mask is the same size as your input.

Comment: Anyway, I suggest you read [the documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga60b4d04b251ba5eb1392c34425497e14) again, `cv2.bitwise_and(og_image, og_image, mask)` applies the AND operation between an image and itself, which is equal to itself, and writes it to `mask`.

Comment: My apologies for all the problems, I have removed all the unnecessary code and replaced the screen capture with images, so they are the same size. I did look at the documentation and figured out my mistake, I just had to take care of the arguments and their position - replaced ```cv2.bitwise_and(og_image, og_image, mask)``` with ```cv2.bitwise_and(og_image, og_image, mask=mask)``` and it works. thanks for the help, everyone. and sorry for the trouble.